# docker how do I know if an update was pulled from repository

Tags: docker

I got a docker repository that I work on and a bot that constantly pulls it from the repo to keep everything in sync but I need a way to find out if, when I pull, an update was downloaded so I can restart the daemon.

Is there a way with the registry itself or something else I could find out if an update was downloaded or not? I hope I'm making sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always I seem to find an answer within minutes. For anyone else interested in a solution for this just do a `docker inspect __repo__` before running a `docker pull __repo__` and save the `id` or `created` date in a variable then run inspect again and see if the data does match. If it doesn't you just pulled an update and your bot could issue a restart on the container.